# How to debug an unwanted subdomain redirect?

Tags: redirects, wordpress, subdomain, magento

I am trying to switch a dated Magento site in the domain root of a website I am developing (`example.com`) with a WordPress site located at `beta.example.com`.  First, I want to move the Magento site to `legacy.example.com` in case visitors need to access it later.  I simply copied all the folders from the root directory to the legacy subdomain directory.

However, when I visit `legacy.example.com`, it redirects me to `example.com` immediately.  If I visit any Magento page on the legacy subdomain it redirects me to `example.com` (the default index) as well.  However, if I visit an independent HTML page that I made such as `legacy.example.com/index.html` the subdomain does not redirect.

I looked at the *.htaccess* file located in the main directory for `example.com` (I copied it to the legacy subdomain along with all the other Magento files) but I can't figure out what exactly is causing the redirect.

How can I find out what exactly is causing the redirect here?  The WordPress site located at `beta.example.com`does not have any redirect issues.  What is the problem with the Magento site?

**UPDATE:**

Deleting the entire .htaccess file in the legacy subdomain does not affect the redirect.  Is it possible that index.php redirects? I couldn't find a redirect myself in the code shown below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.2.0', '<')===true) {
    echo  '<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
<h3 style="margin:0; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none; text-align:left; color:#2f2f2f;">
Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.</h3></div><p>Magento supports PHP 5.2.0 or newer.
<a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/install" target="">Find out</a> how to install</a>
 Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.</p></div>';
    exit;
}

/**
 * Error reporting
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

/**
 * Compilation includes configuration file
 */
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}

require_once $mageFilename;

#Varien_Profiler::enable();

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: Since all requests (for non-existent / Magento files) go through the front controller (`index.php`) I would guess that it is Magento itself that is perhaps triggering the redirect?

Comment: As well, I would like to warn you and anyone that simply copying an .htaccess from a parent domain to a sub-domain will often not work without modification depending on the code of course. Many times, using an .htaccess file from a CMS or other similar install is not immediately transferable to a sub-domain at least.

Comment: Is it easy enough to figure out what I need to change or will I need a lot of background knowledge of PHP/.htaccess files?  I didn't see any redirects that I could tell in index.php but I could post that too if that would help.